# Change value via JavaScript in Yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

I have two fields (field a and field b) in my yii2 application. When I change the value of field a (it's  dropdown list) i want to change the value of field b automatically. For example if i change the value of field a to "12", the value of field b should become "13".

```
<script>
var textbox2 = document.getElementById("model_fielda");
    textbox2.onchange = function(){
    value = document.getElementById("model_fielda").value;          
    if(value ==  12){
     document.getElementById("model_fieldb").value == 13;
    }
 };
</script>
```

Comment: In your view you have to use _$this->registerJs( .. your js code ..)_: More info in the [Docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-client-scripts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution! Instead of document.getElementById("model_fieldb").value == 13;
i had to sete only one "=":

```
 document.getElementById("model_fieldb").value = 13;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
in a view:

```
<?= Html::dropDownList("A",null,ArrayHelper::map(A::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name'),[
  "class"=>"form form-control",
  "prompt"=>Yii::t('template', 'Select anything ...'),
  'onchange'=>'
      $.get("route/to/action/A?param='.'"+$(this).val(),function(data){
          $("select#idOfBSelct").html(data);
      });'
]);?>


<?= Html::dropDownList("B",null,[],[
  "class"=>"form form-control",
  "id"=>"idOfBSelct",
  "prompt"=>Yii::t('template', 'Select anything ...'),
]);?>
```

in a controller:

```
public function actionA()
{
    $dataFromAjax = Yii::$app->request->getQury('param');

    // do something with $dataFromAjax what you want
    return $anyResult;
}
```